# syntastic goes renegade: how to disable checking files in /usr/include/*.h

Tags: c, vim, syntastic

Err. I can't say much, see this image:

[image: vim: left pane , my vimrc, right pane: c code]

On the left pane you my vimrc, on the right pane: c code. On the bottom, undesirable 
synstastic warnings, errors, etc.

My question: How do you make syntastic check only my source code and not everything included
in `/usr/include` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the source Luke ...

Just read into the [source of the syntax checker of C](http://thelackthereof.org/docs/dotfiles/.vim/bundle/syntastic/syntax_checkers/c.vim):

```
let g:syntastic_c_remove_include_errors = 1
```